# Excel: trace dependents of defined names

Tags: excel, vba, formula

Is there an easy way to trace dependencies of Excel Defined names?
Like, which cells are dependent on a specific name?
Or more specific to my needs: how to make sure a Defined name is not used so I can delete it?

Comment: Use an auditing tool - google search is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging mode is Alt + T(ools), (Formula A)U(diting), T(race Precedents).

Recording says

```
Selection.ShowPrecedents
```